# How to handle objects that can be null in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I want a function to return either an object or null.

Here is how I handle it today:

```
export interface MyObject {
    id: string
}

function test(id) : MyObject | null {
    if (!id) {
        return null;
    }

    return {
        id: id
    }
}
```

Is this best practice?

I would prefer to make the interface nullable rather than returning `MyObject | null`.

But I don't know if that is possible.

Comment: Seems like it not possible and you did the best option : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23477

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this best practice?

It's just fine. Everybody does that (or with `undefined`).

> I would prefer to make the interface nullable rather than returning `MyObject | null`.

You can do:

```
export type NullableObject = null | {
  id: string
}
```

It is uncommon but fine too.

Answer (score 1):

In Typescript, null and undefined are part of the domains of all types, unless strict null checks are enabled. In my opinion, explicitly declaring nulls is a much better practice than having them everywhere implicitly, but in the real world it is often not realistic to enable strict mode when interoperating with library code that isn't designed for it.

Comment: Do you think I am already following best practice or is there a better way to explicitly declare nulls?

Answer (score 0):

This should handle null case too (if --strictFunctionTypes compiler option is off)

```
function test(id) : MyObject {
    if (!id) {
        return null;
    }

    return {
        id: id
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! However, I don't think I want to turn that off yet. I don't know TypeScript well enough to start turning things off.

Comment: @user1283776 more info about your question is [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7426)